# How many quakes have been detected by InSight?

Tags: mars, earth-like-planet, geology, quake

Insight has been on Mars with its seismometer for almost two years now. Has it detected any mars-quakes yet? How often do these quakes seem to occur?

Is there a website where the current number of quakes detected by insight is indicated?

Comment: Related but in Space SE, but perhaps old now and I don't see anything about a website where the current number of quakes is indicated. I think your question should have an new, updated answer here. [Has Mars quaked yet? Any scientific speculation when it might?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38543/12102)

Comment: https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/science/research-papers/open-archives has possibly updated information if you look at the 2020 and 2021 papers listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

This is the latest catalogue from seismic events recorded by InSight: [Mars Seismic Catalogue, InSight Mission; V5 2021-01-04](https://www.seis-insight.eu/static/mqs-catalogs/v5/mars_seismic_catalogue_insight_v5_end_2020-10-12_release_2021-01-04.pdf). This report includes seismic events **up to October 12, 2020**. These documents get periodicaly published, so keep an eye on the [page pointed out by @planetmaker](https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/science/research-papers/open-archives) on the comments. The robot has measured a total of 1759 *Marsquake events* as of the report date. Keep in mind that 1034 of those events are of suspicious quality, meaning that the signal may not be attributable to a seism. Setting dubious events aside, in the period of 686 days, the mission  has detected about one quake per day. I could not find any website with live data.

Comment: How exactly did you get that number? Going through the provided data XMLs? Or somehow else?

Comment: I just added all the recorded frequencys shown in the catalogue; from low to super high ones. I then substracted all records with bad quality to the total and divided the result by the number of days since landing (26 Nov, 2018) till report date to get a daily average.

Comment: I doubt that 1000 quakes per day is an accurate number. It's a 1000 measurements with believable data - but most will not contain quakes. Most recorded motion is - according to a very shallow skipping through the literature - attributed to wind influence.

Comment: Sorry if the notation confused you, its arround 1 per day.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. I changed the decimal separator to dot ss that is used in English. The comma usually denotes the thousand separator

Comment: I think the last bit still needs an edit: "the mission has measured an average of 1.057 quakes per day since landing (686 days)" Perhaps "per day" should be deleted?

Comment: If you think that it is self-explanatory that 1.057 quakes refers to a daily average then please, do change it.

Comment: the "per day" or a "daily" is essential to understand the number. I'd actually write it slightley less accurate "Setting dubious events aside, in the period of 686 days, the mission has detected about one quake per day"